How to construct XML node from string with namespace?
I am trying to create a xmlNode from an XML string with xmlParseBalancedChunkMemory but when the XML string containing a prefix/namespace in it, libxml2 would throw error 201 (XML_NS_ERR_UNDEFINED_NAMESPACE). What is the proper way to parse an XML string?
The code I used to parse the XML string:
    xmlNodePtr newNode = nullptr;
    // int rc = xmlParseBalancedChunkMemory(doc, NULL, NULL, 0,
    //                                 BAD_CAST content,
    //                                 &newNode);
    int rc = xmlParseBalancedChunkMemoryRecover(doc, NULL, NULL, 0,
                                     BAD_CAST content,
                                     &newNode, 1);

The XML string I'm trying to parse:
<ds:X509Certificate>MII...blah</ds:X509Certificate>

The error being thrown:
libxml<Err>: namespace 
libxml<Err>: error : 
libxml<Err>: Namespace prefix ds on X509Certificate is not defined
libxml<Err>: <ds:X509Certificate>MII...blah</ds:X509Certificate>
libxml<Err>:   

I don't understand why it throws that error when the doc being passed already contains the namespace definitions.
<EDSCrate xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

PS: the same code worked fine on normal, non-prefixed, XML strings such as <a>helloworld</a> or helloworld (text node).
Update:
Added minimal reproducible example...
libxml2-troubleshoot1$ ./main2
<root xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
XML string is valid
namespace error : Namespace prefix ds on X509Certificate is not defined
<ds:X509Certificate>MII...SigningCertificate</ds:X509Certificate>
                   ^
Namespace is the root cause but how to fix it?

Update2:
I have found 2 workarounds (which I hate) for libxml2 to create the node without throwing an error... however, the end result is that I ended up having extra xmlns:ds attribute in my node. I feel like this is a bug on libxml2 not correctly parsing through the available namespaces.
Workaround #1, make a normal node, then set the NS:
xmlNodePtr newNode = nullptr;
xmlParseBalancedChunkMemory(doc, NULL, NULL, 0,
                            BAD_CAST content,
                            &newNode) == 0;
xmlSetNs(newNode, nsMap[prefix]);

// result:
<ds:X509Certificate xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">MII...SigningCertificate</ds:X509Certificate>

Workaround #2, use xmlNewDocNode:
// I now have to split the name and content
// This probably won't work either if nested content has ns too
// name: "X509Certificate"
// content: "MII...SigningCertificate"
xmlNewDocNode(doc, nsMap[prefix], BAD_CAST name, BAD_CAST content);

// result:
<ds:X509Certificate xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">MII...SigningCertificate</ds:X509Certificate>

Full actual code:
#include <libxml/c14n.h>
#include <libxml/xmlschemas.h>


// For xmlSubstituteEntitiesDefault deprecation:
//  xmlSubstituteEntitiesDefault(1) > XML_PARSE_NOENT
// For xmlLoadExtDtdDefaultValue deprecation:
//  XML_DETECT_IDS > XML_PARSE_DTDLOAD
//  XML_COMPLETE_ATTRS > XML_PARSE_DTDATTR 
#define XMLMGR_PARSER_OPTIONS               (XML_PARSE_RECOVER | XML_PARSE_NOENT | XML_PARSE_DTDLOAD | XML_PARSE_DTDATTR | XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS | XML_PARSE_HUGE)

const char* dump(xmlDocPtr doc, bool pretty = true)
{
    xmlNodePtr root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
    xmlBufferPtr buf = xmlBufferCreate();
    if (buf == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dump: failed to create buffer\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    xmlNodeDump(buf, doc, root, 0, pretty ? 1 : 0);
    return buf->use > 0 ? (const char*) buf->content : NULL;
}

bool load(xmlDocPtr &doc, const char* xml) {
    doc = xmlReadDoc((const xmlChar *) xml, NULL, NULL, XMLMGR_PARSER_OPTIONS);
    return doc != NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argp)
{
    xmlInitParser();
    LIBXML_TEST_VERSION

    xmlDocPtr doc = NULL;

    const char* sample = "<root xmlns:ds='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'></root>";
    if (load(doc, sample))
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", dump(doc));

        bool ok = false;
        xmlNodePtr newNode = nullptr;

        ok = xmlParseBalancedChunkMemory(doc, NULL, NULL, 0,
                                         BAD_CAST "<X509Certificate>MII...SigningCertificate</X509Certificate>",
                                         &newNode) == 0;
        if (ok)
            fprintf(stdout, "XML string is valid\n");

        ok = xmlParseBalancedChunkMemory(doc, NULL, NULL, 0,
                                         BAD_CAST "<ds:X509Certificate>MII...SigningCertificate</ds:X509Certificate>",
                                         &newNode) == 0;

        if (!ok)
            fprintf(stdout, "Namespace is the root cause but how to fix it?\n");

        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    }

    return 0;
}

and actual output:
<root xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
XML string is valid
namespace error : Namespace prefix ds on X509Certificate is not defined
<ds:X509Certificate>MII...SigningCertificate</ds:X509Certificate>
                   ^


Please provide [mcve]. One node from xml and one call of C function is not MCVE. Based on error it looks like xml is invalid. You can use this side to validate your xml: https://www.xmlvalidation.com/

I looks like you have extracted a string from a document, and are trying to parse that string without the enclosing document and the namespace definitions it contains. But I'm only guessing, one line of code and two lines of XML are not enough to know what the issue is. Please provide a [mre].

The namespace definition has to be on a parent node of the node being used.

Nice, will try your github example later

@MarekR I've updated the question with 2 potentially ugly workarounds, but I really hate having xmlns:ds everywhere...

You should probably use xmlParseInNodeContext and set up a context node with the needed namespaces.

I finally had time to see your code. What are you doing? Why you reading this xml in those strange unrelated pieces? This is fundamentally wrong.
Here is some test application which works for me perfectly:
#include <iostream>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>

constexpr xmlChar DS_NAMESPACE[] = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#";
constexpr char filename[] = "demo_data.xml";

void process_xml_tree(xmlDocPtr doc)
{
    xmlNodePtr root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    xmlNodePtr cur = root->children;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE &&
            xmlStrcmp(cur->name, BAD_CAST "X509Certificate") == 0 &&
            xmlStrcmp(cur->ns->href, DS_NAMESPACE) == 0) {
            xmlChar* content = xmlNodeGetContent(cur);
            if (content != NULL) {
                std::cout << "X509Certificate: " << content << std::endl;
                xmlFree(content);
            }
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    LIBXML_TEST_VERSION

    xmlDocPtr doc = xmlReadFile(filename, NULL, 0);
    if (doc == NULL) {
        perror(filename);
        return -1;
    }
    process_xml_tree(doc);
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    xmlCleanupParser();

    return 0;
}

I used this file demo_data.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root xmlns:ds='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'>
    <ds:X509Certificate>MII...SigningCertificate</ds:X509Certificate>
</root>

And the output is:
X509Certificate: MII...SigningCertificate

Offtopoic:
Such short code post inside a question, so this is clearly visible without jumping to other sites (I will update your question to cover this).

I have no problem reading the XML doc... It only throw errors when I try to CREATE an XML node. If you check my minimal reproducible repo, I am using xmlParseBalancedChunkMemory around line 45, creating a node with ds: in there. That's where libxml2 gave me those error messages.
